# How to do React forceUpdate() to a child component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I can **force reload** for a parent component with `this.forceUpdate()`, but how to do it for a child component?

i.e. following react class methods:

```
buttonClick = () => {
   //This updates parent (this) component
   this.forceUpdate(); 

  //This causes runtime error ("..not a function in buttonClick...")
   Rtable.forceUpdate();
}

render () {
  <div>
     <RTable />
  </div>
}
```

Comment: Pass a prop from your buttonClick to the `RTable` component, within `RTable` read the prop and trigger a forceUpdate inside that component.

Comment: Can we know why you want to force update of the child component? Maybe there's a better solution to that problem

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If child component **is not memoized** then rendering its parent **will render** the child.

If child component **is memoized**, you could force update with its **reference**.

And of course, passing different properties to a child, changing its state, will re-render it.

> Changing the [key](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html) will **UNMOUNT** the component, it is like making a [conditional rendering](https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html) on it.

Here is an example demonstating everything mentioned:

```
class Child extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    console.log("mounted");
  }
  render() {
    console.log("rendered");
    return <div>Child</div>;
  }
}

class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    counter: 0
  };

  childRef = React.createRef();
  onClick = () => this.forceUpdate();
  onCounter = () => this.setState({ counter: this.state.counter + 1 });
  onRef = () => this.childRef.current.forceUpdate();

  render() {
    return (
      <>
        <Child key={this.state.counter} ref={this.childRef} />
        <button onClick={this.onClick}>Render</button>
        <button onClick={this.onCounter}>Update Key</button>
        <button onClick={this.onRef}>Render with ref</button>
      </>
    );
  }
}
```

[image: Edit lucid-hill-vfvr3]

Comment: Actually this was also indirectly an answer to a question that i did not managed to ask. My child component (npm react-table) uses memoized data and it did not update it with state change. When i changed the way useMemo() is called in the child module, it started updating the content in the table.

Comment: @KajRisberg, could you please provide your solution as an answer?

Answer (score 1):

`<RTable key={some variable that changes between renders} />`

As pointed out below this will cause unmount, which causes the child to lose its state and also run `componentWillUnmount`, `componentDidMount` and `constructor` methods (which may be useful when you want to resubscribe).

Documentation https://reactjs.org/docs/glossary.html#keys

Comment: That does not remove runtime error? I don't want to update a state variable, but to force a re-mount of a whole component.

Comment: This is a wrong answer, you are **UNMOUNTING** the component, in the same way you could do it in the parent.

Comment: @KajRisberg yes, sorry that line should be removed, just adding unique key guarantees it will be rendered again

Comment: @DennisVash Unmounting guarantees it will be rendered again, so it should do what's required. Is it just wrong terminology?

Comment: Rendering and Unmounting are different things, in your example, you **will lose** the current the state of the component.

Comment: Changing the key means: Unmount the current component, mount the same instance with the initial state - It is not - rendering. Note the OP tries to make `RTable.forceUpdate()` which is - rerendering.

Comment: I see, that's a great point. It's actually the reason why I ever wanted to force a rerender.

Comment: Oh boy how how silly i am. forceUpdate() is indeed rendering instead of re-mounting that i thought it was. I will edit that silly little question.

Comment: @KajRisberg Instead try asking a new question, thats a good and not trivial question, should stay as it is